# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот код:

```
var goods = {
    "11292" : {
        "name" : "Фитнес Браслет",
        "cost" : "500",
        "img" : "images/fit-braslet.png",
        "sklad" : "Да"
    },
        "11294" : {
        "name" : "Колонка JBL Charge 3",
        "cost" : "3500",
        "img" : "images/jbl-charge3.png",
        "sklad" : "Да"

};

console.log(goods);
```

Когда смотрю в консоль, то выскакивает:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: Блин, три плюса на опечатку? Народ, серьёзно?

Comment: @andreymal, сам удивлён(если не сказать крепче). Это видимо магия метки "JavaScript".

Comment: А я не в шоке - видел у PHP колдунство ещё сильнее ))

Answer (score 4):

Не закрыт второй 11294 объект (забыли фигурную скобку)

```
var goods = {
    "11292" : {
        "name" : "Фитнес Браслет",
        "cost" : "500",
        "img" : "images/fit-braslet.png",
        "sklad" : "Да"
    },
    "11294" : {
        "name" : "Колонка JBL Charge 3",
        "cost" : "3500",
        "img" : "images/jbl-charge3.png",
        "sklad" : "Да"
    }
};

console.log(goods);
```